# Create Javascript object of elements by ID

Tags: javascript, object, dom

So, in order to make my code clearer, I made this element-object:

```
var elements = new (function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        this[arguments[i]] = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
})("messages", "title", "link", "news");
```

Basically, it creates an object with the keys the same as their element with that ID.

Is there any more "elegant" way to do this, instead of using arguments and a loop?

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ Preferably ES5, nice one though.

Comment: Of course, you know that properties with id as key already hang off the window. although using this feature is vaguely deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to achieve this more elegantly

```
var elements = ["messages", "title", "link", "news"].reduce(function (memo, key) {
  memo[key] = document.getElementById(key);
  return memo;
}, {});
```

If you prefer [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), you can use it like this

```
var elements = {};
["messages", "title", "link", "news"].forEach(function (key) {
  this[key] = document.getElementById(key);
}, elements);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start off by creating a simple utility routine to turn a list of keys and list of values into an object. Let this be an exercise for the reader, call it `keys_and_values_to_object`. This is essentially the same as Underscores `_.object`.

Then:

```
function get_elements(ids) {
  return keys_and_values_to_object(ids, ids.map(id => document.getElementById(id)));
}
```

To decompose this further, we could also write a routine which maps an array to an object:

```
function map_array_to_object(array, fn) {
  return keys_and_values_to_object(array, array.map(fn));
}
```

Now we can write

```
function get_elements(ids) {
  return map_array_to_object(ids, id => document.getElementById(id));
}
```

Or if you prefer

```
function get_elements(ids) {
  return map_array_to_object(ids, document.getElementById.bind(document));
}
```

If you want to pass the list of ids as parameters instead of an array, adjust accordingly.

#### PS

OK, if you really want to see how `keys_and_values_to_object` might be written, then here's some alternatives:

```
function keys_and_values_to_object(keys, values) {
  return keys.reduce((result, key, idx) => {
    result[key] = values[idx];
    return result;
  }, {});
}

function keys_and_values_to_object(keys, values) {
  return Object.assign({}, ...keys.map((key, idx) => ({[key]: values[idx]})));
}

function keys_and_values_to_object(keys, values) {
  var result = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) result[keys[i]] = values[i];
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need it to be a function, in ES5 I'd write:

```
function elementObject() {
  [].slice.call(arguments).forEach(function (i) {
      this[i] = document.getElementById(i);
  }, this);
}

// use it like this
var elements = new elementObject("messages", "title", "link", "news");
var other_elements = new elementObject("a", "b", "c");
```

But it would be much nicer in ES6

```
function elementObject() {
    Array.from(arguments).forEach(i => this[i] = document.getElementById(i));
}

// use it like this
var elements = new elementObject("messages", "title", "link", "news");
var other_elements = new elementObject("a", "b", "c");
```

If you don't need it to be a function, and you are not going to use it often in your code, you can use the same code, with just an array:

```
var elements = {};
["messages", "title", "link", "news"].forEach(function (i) {
  this[i] = document.getElementById(i);
}, elements);
```

Comment: Where in the code? I mean how should I implement this with my array of element ids?

Comment: But arrow functions cannot be used as constructors.

Comment: @torazaburo Sorry, I forgot that when I updated the answer. I just updated again to reflect this. Thanks.